# Is it possible to login an identity provider with a google account and register a different email account?

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid, idp

I’m looking for an open source identity provider which I can login via my google account. I.e. the idp can forward my authentication request to google. At the same time I can register a different email account with the idp like someone@foo.com so that the JTW returned containing someone@foo.com rather than my gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

That is just a case of running custom logic that operates on user account attributes and authentication attributes. Look for extensibility in these areas:

- Actions or steps that run after authentication
- The ability to create a user account and populate its attributes in your preferred way
- Claims issuing features that lookup values from the account, after the user is identified

We are not meant to recommend particular providers on SO. But do some research into systems with these capabilities.